# Filter by only red values in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make a program that uses my webcam in processing 3.x that will filter green and blue, from an image and show either red and black or white. I've tried two ways that I think should work, but I must be missing something here because my whole screen just goes black when I switch to this red mode.

Attempt 1:

```java
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
   for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
      set(x,y,color(red(x+(y*width)),0,0));
   }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```java
// inputImage is the image on my screen of type PImage.
for(int c = 0; c < inputImage.pixels.length; c++){
   inputImage.pixels[c] = color(red(c),0,0);
}
```

Both attempts resulted in a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt 2 is clearer way to do it, so I'll address that.

You need to call `loadPixels()` on the `inputImage` before you write to the `pixels[]` array and finally call `updatePixels()` to apply write changes.

You had also called `red()` on `c` (the loop index), not on `img.pixels[c]`.

**Result**

```
inputImage.loadPixels();
for (int c = 0; c < inputImage.pixels.length; c++) {
    img.pixels[c] = color(red(img.pixels[c]), 0, 0);
}
inputImage.updatePixels();
```

If you need the code to be faster consider setting the color without 2 method calls (to `color()` and `red()`) with this bit-mask:

`img.pixels[c] = img.pixels[c] & 0xFF0000;`